# Create logical vector of first matching condition

Tags: r, vector, match

How can one create a logical vector that has TRUE for the first matching condition and FALSE otherwise?

```r
v = rep(1:4, 3)
v == 3
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

`==` gives TRUE for all values that equals 3, but I want only the first one to be TRUE:

```r
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I came up with potential solutions but it always uses the index and then construct the logical vector, and I was wondering if there were simpler one.

```r
tabulate(match(3, v), nbins = length(v))
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

seq_along(v) == min(which(v == 3))
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
v==3&!duplicated(v)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or

```
seq_along(v)==match(3,v)
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

In negated vector `replace`ing `which.max` of comparison with `TRUE`.

```
replace(!v, which.max(v == 3), TRUE)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or modulo combined with `cumsum`s.

```
cumsum(cumsum(v %% 3 == 0)) == 1
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```